# How to convert values to ToUpper from values in Get-WMIObject Win32_Printer

Tags: powershell, toupper

Trying to write a script to remove all network printers from a system but leave the other printers / fax alone.

```
$Printer = Get-WMIObject Win32_Printer | Select-Object ServerName, ShareName
```

to get the values for `$Printer` but cannot get it to change to uppercase.
`@{ServerName=\\HBMN-Vbranch; ShareName=HBMN-P5}` is returned but I am trying to do `if ($Printer -Like "*\\HBMN-VBRANCH*")` and it never finds the lower case or mixed case.

If I try to do `$($Printer.ToString().ToUpper())` no value is returned.
If I try `$Printer.ToUpper()` method is not found.

Comment: As an aside: your problem is unrelated to character _case_: PowerShell's string operations are case-_insensitive_ by default.

Answer (score 1):

`.toUpper()` is a method for strings.  So convert that output to a string using `out-string`:

```
($printer.SystemName|out-string).toUpper()
```

Comment: I assume you meant `.ServerName`, not `.SystemName`, which already _is_ a string, so you can just call `.ToUpper()` directly on it. More importantly: Not only is piping to `Out-String` a very inefficient way to convert objects to strings (though sometimes it is the right tool), it also _appends a newline_ to something that's already a string, which is undesired. Finally, PowerShell's operators such as `-like` are case-_insensitive_, so there's no need for case conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `ToString()` on `$Printer` does not convert the custom object (PSCustomObject) to string, that's your basic problem. This should work:

```
$Printer.ServerName.ToUpper()
```

But if you don't need the share name in the custom object, just get the server name as string:

```
$serverName = Get-WMIObject Win32_Printer | Select-Object -ExpandProperty ServerName
```

Furthermore, your comparison should use the server name, not the `$Printer` object:

```
if ($Printer.ServerName -like "*HBMN-VBRANCH*")
```

Comment: Glad to hear we arrived at a shared understanding (+1).